# How can i get a list of total sums based off names in a table and their points (from column)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How can i get a list from the table below to show who was first, second, third. etc. based off the amount of points?

I've used countif, but can only either get their name or points max.

[image: Table of info]

I've tried this but can only figure out how to get the sum's in that column.

[image]

Preferable listed as so;

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. How are you adding points up? How are you deriving the results you show in your second table?  Are the Names really `Q1..Q6` as you show in the Name column of your first table?  What results do you expect to see in your third table, given the data you present?

Comment: to clear it up, ignore the names, just say they're questions im using the colomn 5points, 3points etc to gauge that persons total points so Will earnt 5 points on Q1, James 3 points on Q1 etc. Hope that clears it up

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula solution can adopt in Excel 2010 to 2019, include the OP's Excel 2016

**1. Intermediate Table** set up in Column K:L

1.1] In "UniqueName" `K2`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(TEXT(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($2:$7)/1%+{2,3,4,5}/(COUNTIF(K$1:K1,$B$2:$E$7&"")=0),1),"R0C00"),0),"")
```

1.2] In "TotalScore" `L2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(K2="","",SUMPRODUCT((B$2:E$7=K2)*{5,3,2,1}))
```

**2. Result Table** set up in Column G:I with criteria in Column G

2.1] In "Point" `H2`, formula copied down :

```
=LARGE($L$2:$L$12,ROW(A1))
```

2.2] In "Name" `I2`, formula copied down :

```
=INDEX(K:K,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($K$2:$K$12)/($L$2:$L$12=H2),COUNTIF(H$2:H2,H2)))
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great, exactly what I was looking for! Except I can't generate the names after K2, K3 (once copied comes up with Will)

Comment: All good, it's automated once in the table, great work thanks!

Comment: Just a quick question, if i wanted to add another coloumn or two before A, how can i change the first formula to ignore them, to get to the names?

Comment: If 2 columns added  before col A, "UniqueName" shifted to M2, then formula become :=IFERROR(INDIRECT(TEXT(AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($2:$7)/1%+{4,5,6,7}/(COUNTIF(M$1:M1,$D$2:$G$7&"")=0),1),"R0C00"),0),"")

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows Excel O365, you can do this with an intermediate table and complex formulas.

If you do not, Power Query is arguably a better choice.

**Original Data**

[image]

**Intermediate Table** *anyplace on the worksheet, to give a total score for each person*

*In this case, the data is in `H8:I18`*

```
H7: Total Score
I7: Name
I8: =UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,Scores[[5Points]:[1Point]])&"</s></t>","//s"))
H8: =SUM(IFERROR(1/(I8=Scores[[5Points]:[1Point]])*{5,3,2,1},""))  and fill down to match the "Name" column
```

[image]

**Final Results**

```
C13: Pts
D13: Name
B14:B17 1st|2nd|3rd|4th

C14:  =INDEX(SORT(H8:I18,1,-1),{1;2;3;4},{1,2})
```

[image]

As I wrote, if you don't have O365 but do have Excel 2010+, you can use Power Query.  The Table representing the **Original Data** is named `Scores`. If you name it differently, change the table name in Line 2 of the code.

*I suggest you review the Applied Steps that will appear when you paste the code into the Advanced Editor in Power Query, and also read the annotations in the code to understand what is going on*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Scores"]}[Content],

//Remove unneeded first column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"Name"}),

//Unpivot all columns to create a single Name column
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Columns", {}, "Attribute", "Name"),

//Split of the point amount from the original column Headers
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(
            #"Unpivoted Columns", "Attribute", 
            Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({"0".."9"}, (c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c)),
            {"Attribute.1"}),

//Set the appropriate data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Character Transition",{{"Attribute.1", Int64.Type}, {"Name", type text}}),

//Group by "Name" and aggregate the SUM
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Name"}, {{"Pts", each List.Sum([Attribute.1]), type nullable number}}),
    
//Find the fourth largest value
    max4 = List.MaxN(Table.Column(#"Grouped Rows","Pts"),4),
    threshold = List.Last(max4),

//Filter for the top 4 items and sort descending
    top4 = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each [Pts] >= threshold),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(top4,{{"Pts", Order.Descending}}),

//Convert to Ordinal values for Rank column
//Note that if you will be returning ranks > 9, will need to change the List.ContainsAny Values to be only the last digit
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Rank", each if List.ContainsAny({0,4..9},{[Index]}) then 
            Number.ToText([Index],"0'th'") else 
          if List.ContainsAny({2,3},{[Index]}) then 
            Number.ToText([Index],"0nd") else 
            Number.ToText([Index],"0st")),

//Remove unwanted Index column and re-order the columns
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{"Rank", "Pts", "Name"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: I'm using 2016 for this, but i'll try when I get home later today. Looks good though!

Comment: @Jube As I wrote, that solution is for Windows O365. I don't think you have the functions available to you in 2016.  I'll add a Power Query solution.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but with the solution below, I'll be marking it as the answer. Once I get the names changing from the first formula